# Modifying \part style in KOMA

Tags: koma-script, book-design

I've got the design for `part` style in my KOMA document.  It requires:

- removing "Part" text
- changing font
- flushing text to bottom right.

I have already done some reading, removed "Part" text and changed font.  But I have no idea how to make text flush to bottom right.  Please, can you help me with this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=235mm,top=20mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=65mm,marginparsep=7mm,marginparwidth=48mm,headsep=4mm,headheight=6mm]{geometry}

\definecolor{basic}{cmyk}{1.0,0.7,0.5,0}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{part}{\fontsize{36pt}{36pt}\selectfont\color{basic}}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\fontsize{36pt}{36pt}\selectfont\color{basic}}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\thepart.}

\begin{document}

\part{Teorija in problemi}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]Design:
[image]

Comment: Markus Kohm posted a solution for this here http://www.komascript.de/node/1769

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=235mm,top=20mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=65mm,marginparsep=7mm,marginparwidth=48mm,headsep=4mm,headheight=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ilines,headsepline]{scrpage2}
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}

\renewcommand*{\raggedpart}{\raggedleft}
\renewcommand*{\partheadstartvskip}{\null\vfill}

\definecolor{basic}{cmyk}{1.0,0.7,0.5,0}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{part}{\fontsize{36pt}{36pt}\selectfont\color{basic}}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\fontsize{36pt}{36pt}\selectfont\color{basic}}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\thepart.}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\lipsum[1-5]

\mainmatter

\newgeometry{top=20mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=17mm,marginparsep=7mm,marginparwidth=0mm,headsep=4mm,headheight=6mm}
\part{Teorija in problemi}
\restoregeometry

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple, but a bit "hacky" approach: Just add some fills to your font definitions:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=235mm,top=20mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=65mm,marginparsep=7mm,marginparwidth=48mm,headsep=4mm,headheight=6mm]{geometry}

\definecolor{basic}{cmyk}{1.0,0.7,0.5,0}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{part}{\hfill\fontsize{36pt}{36pt}\selectfont\color{basic}}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\vfill\hfill\fontsize{36pt}{36pt}\selectfont\color{basic}}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\thepart.}

\begin{document}

\part{Teorija in problemi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks Daniel.  I found less hacky approach, as stated in my Answer.