# How to prevent from the part name to be at new line?

Tags: koma-script, parts

I using KOMS-script, and I look at this question: [Modifying \part style in KOMA](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142157/modifying-part-style-in-koma), for changing the part style.

My question is: How do I prevent from the  part name to be in a new line....

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\renewcommand\partformat{\partname~\thepart\autodot\enskip}% add space between number and title
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{}% remove the linebreak and vskip
\setkomafont{partprefix}{\usekomafont{part}}% same font(size) for prefix and title
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand\partformat{\partname~\thepart\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{}
\setkomafont{partprefix}{\usekomafont{part}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\part{First Part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or maybe you want:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=\fill,
  afterskip=0pt
]{part}
\renewcommand\raggedpart{\raggedleft}

\renewcommand\partformat{\thepart\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{}
\setkomafont{partprefix}{\usekomafont{part}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\part{First Part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can also use (as asked in a comment below):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=\fill,
  afterskip=0pt
]{part}
\renewcommand\raggedpart{\raggedleft}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{}
\renewcommand\partformat{part~\thepart\autodot\enskip}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}% scalable font
\setkomafont{partprefix}{\fontsize{26pt}{30pt}\selectfont\color{red}}
\setkomafont{part}{\usekomafont{partprefix}\color{blue}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\part{First Part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: See my updated answer. You have to load `xcolor` and you need a scalable font. Note that font element name `partnumber` is an alias of `partprefix`.