# How do I change the ToC style at KOMA-script?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I follow the instructors here:  [How to prevent from the part name to be at new line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456406/how-to-prevent-from-the-part-name-to-be-at-new-line) (I ask it because I want to change the display of the parts at my document).
It works fine,but at the ToC, the part names (and numbering) still appears wrong:
[image]

**It should be `.I` and not `I.`**
How can I fix it?

This is what I put at my preamble....

```
\setkomafont{part}{\itshape\fontsize{26pt}{26pt}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\fontsize{26pt}{26pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{part~ :\thepart~~}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{}
```

Thank you!!

EDIT:
I found this answer: https://komascript.de/node/1418
but when I write:

```
\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[1]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{.\thepart}%
}
```

it doesn't remove the other dot :-(

[image]

Comment: This should be expected behavior. Try `numbers=noeenddot` as class option.

Comment: @TeXnician what do you mean when you write: `numbers=noeenddot` where to put it?

Comment: As a class option (`\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scr*}` with * being your KOMA class' suffix).